# TCP Half-Open Connections, Winsock, Listen/Accept Behavior

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock, listen

As a network engineer, I'm very familiar with TCP operations.  As a programmer, I've dabbled in socket programming but never wrote any production services.

We have a vendor system that integrates with PTZ (pan/tilt/zoom) cameras.  Cameras watch patients.  Camera data gets fed to a vendor server.  Vendor server relays camera data to clients.  (It does more, but this is the simple case.)  If a client wants to adjust the camera, client sends a custom command to a custom service on the vendor server.  Server interprets the command and sends it to the camera.  Camera moves.

We have a problem where the PTZ service on the server is crashing.  During testing, with network captures, we found the service crashed around the time `nmap` performed a half-open (embryonic) connection -- nmap sent the SYN, server replied with SYN/ACK, nmap didn't send the final ACK.  Server sent duplicate SYN/ACKs trying to complete the session and failed.

What I want to understand:  a service uses `listen` to watch for TCP connections, then uses `accept` to accept the connection.  At what point does `listen` tell the service there is a new connection, ready to be `accept`ed?  Does the TCP connection need to be complete before `listen` passes it on to the service to be `accept`ed?  Or does the server just need to return a SYN/ACK before `listen` tells the service?

If the handshake needs to be complete -- SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK -- before `listen` tells the service, then I may be going down the wrong path.  If the socket just needs to get to SYN/ACK, there may be a problem with the service's handling of an incomplete session.  Other testing, where we complete a TCP session and send bogus data trying to get the service to crash -- has not resulted in a failure of the service.  But repeated `nmap` testing pretty reliably crashes it so I'm leaning toward a half-open connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

`listen()` itself simply creates the backlog queue, opens the bound port for communication, and then exits.  *Behind the scenes*, the socket stack is now passively listening for connections at the OS layer, caching pending connections in the backlog queue and completing their handshakes. Only fully established connections are made available to `accept()`, `WSAAccept()`, and `AcceptEx()`.

After `listen()` exits, depending on which mode the application code is using for the socket I/O (blocking, non-blocking, Overlapped I/O, or I/O Completion Port), the code can either:

1. (blocking) call `accept()` or `WSAAccept()` and let it block until it retrieves a connection from the queue.
2. (non-blocking) use `select()`, `WSAAsyncSelect()`, or `WSAEventSelect()` to be notified when a connection is ready and waiting to be retrieved with `accept()` or `WSAAccept()`.
3. (overlapped/iocp) call `AcceptEx()` to begin an asynchronous accept, and then wait for an event/completion notification indicating a connection has been retrieved from the queue.

Comment: I think I've got that.  So picturing the black box that is the vendor's system, the vendor is likely sitting on a `select()` instead of `listen()`.

So on point 2, when the connection is "ready and waiting" . . . does that imply the handshake is complete?  The client has sent the TCP ACK?  Or can it still be "ready and waiting" pending the final client ACK?

Comment: As I stated in my answer: "*Only **fully established** connections are made available to `accept()`, ...*". So yes, a connection's handshake must be complete before the code ever sees the connection.

Comment: Thank you Remy.  Very much appreciated.  That would indicate a half-open connection is not corrupting the service, so it must be something being sent to the service.  But we just can't identify what it is.  Now that I understand how `listen()`, `select()`, and `accept()` work together and with the protocol stack, I'll keep looking.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> At what point does listen tell the service there is a new connection, ready to be accepted?

Never.

> Does the TCP connection need to be complete before listen passes it on to the service to be accepted? Or does the server just need to return a SYN/ACK before listen tells the service?

None of this happens. `listen()` just puts the socket into LISTEN state, and causes TCP to start accepting connections and putting them in the backlog queue. It is `accept()` which communicates with the service: it blocks while the backlog queue is empty (essentially) and then returns the first entry and constructs a new socket around it.

> If the handshake needs to be complete -- SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK -- before listen tells the service, then I may be going down the wrong path.

It needs to be complete before `accept()` will return a new socket to the service.

> If the socket just needs to get to SYN/ACK, there may be a problem with the service's handling of an incomplete session.

Not an issue. It doesn't behave like that.

> Other testing, where we complete a TCP session and send bogus data trying to get the service to crash -- has not resulted in a failure of the service.

QED.

> But repeated nmap testing pretty reliably crashes it so I'm leaning toward a half-open connection problem.

Please define 'crashing'.

Comment: Vendor service, so can't be explicit on "crashing."  "Lock up" may be a better term, but we can't know for sure.  No log entries.  Camera controls gray out on client and server screens, unable to move the camera, sometimes camera will randomly point in different direction on failure.  Restarting the PTZ service works 4 out of 5 times; other times server requires reboot.  Vendor says port scans known to cause problems.  We're trying to establish exact circumstances and cause so we can tell vendor Fix Your Stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> nmap sent the SYN, server replied with SYN/ACK, nmap didn't send the 
>> final ACK. Server sent duplicate SYN/ACKs trying to complete the 
>> session and failed.
```

This could be the RST from the client not getting transmitted by a firewall or intermediate device to the server endpoint. This has been something of an industry issue for a while since vendors changed tcp stacks to mitigate for the blind reset attack. Firewall has to change to allow the RST transmission, so the server knows to tear down the embryonic state. Most firewalls aren't configured to do that by default.

Some info here:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5961#page-9

```
https://knowledgebase.paloaltonetworks.com/KCSArticleDetail?id=kA10g000000boBJCAY
```